# put text body above the pasted range

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

i have a code below that paste a range into an email body but my problem is the text body **This is the body:** is below the pasted range when the code is ran, maybe someone can help how to put it above the pasted range

```
Sub SendEmailWithRange()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim doc As Object
    
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").CurrentRegion
    
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display 'Change to .Send to send the email immediately
        .Body = "This is the body:" '& vbNewLine & vbNewLine
            Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
            MyRange.Copy
            doc.Range(x, x).Paste
        .To = Range("I3").Value
        .Subject = "My subject"
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set x before you paste.
`x = doc.Range.End - 1` finds the end of the document less 1

```
    Sub SendEmailWithRange()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim doc As Object
    
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").CurrentRegion
    
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display                                 'Change to .Send to send the email immediately
        
        .Body = "This is the body:"              '& vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        MyRange.Copy
        doc.Range(x).Paste
            
        .To = Range("I3").Value
        .Subject = "My subject"
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Add more lines to bottom of body

```
    Sub SendEmailWithRange()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim doc As Object
    
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").CurrentRegion
    
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display                                 'Change to .Send to send the email immediately
        
        .Body = "This is the body:"              '& vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        MyRange.Copy
        doc.Range(x).Paste
            
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        doc.Range(x) = "More Stuff"              'add more stuff
        
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        doc.Range(x) = vbNewLine & "Even More Stuff" 'add more stuff with New line
        
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        doc.Range(x) = vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                       "Even More Stuff"         'add more stuff with multi-line breaks
        
        .To = Range("I3").Value
        .Subject = "My subject"
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, it works. If i want to put a `Regards, John Doe at the bottom of the body which is below the pasted range how would i do that?

Comment: Just keep adding lines, I have added another code showing this.